# Cannot add DataTables.net javascript into Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I've been having this problem where i couldn't add Datatables.net javascript into my Joomla article. I have been trying to include it through Jumi.

To say that my editor strips of the  tag is somewhat not right as I have been able to execute Google Chart API in Joomla which also uses javascript.

Any clue why?

The code is as below :

```
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have disabled mootools (the default javascript library in Joomla 1.5), then the jquery may well be causing a conflict.

Instead of using `$` try using `jQuery`, ie

> jQuery(document).ready

The datatables javascript may also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag `<link>` is not allowed in the `<body>`. Edit the `index.php` of the template to include the `<link>` and remove it from the code to be included in the article.

Comment: This is not good practice as it will likely be wiped out with a template update or change.

Comment: Only when you are stupid enough not to create your own copy of a template when you are going to use it. Or updating without having a backup that you know works because you installed it somewhere else. But yes, those people exist!

Comment: It's bad practice to modify component core files regardless of backup protocol. It makes for more maintenance and should always be considered a last resort.

Comment: Indeed, a lot of people are of that opinion. I disagree, don't consider that bad practise provided you realize the consequenses of customizing. No matter whether you do it in core, via overrides or create your own extensions. The moment you customize/extend you need to migrate instead simply update!